# Deleting an object without calling its overriden delete operator?

Tags: c++, memory, delete-operator

I am working on a system that is not my own, and need to delete an object from a context that was not originally considered when the system was created.

The delete function of `my_class` uses a dynamic allocator/deallocator that is assigned to each working thread. I have introduced a new thread (which doesn't currently have this functionality) that needs to be able to delete and free the memory of the object as 'normal'.

Is there a way to do this? I am looking for any old quick/messy solution so that I can execute my program asap (it appears to be running out of memory).

EDIT: Perhaps more context.

The class' delete operator:

```
void my_class::operator delete( void * p ) {
       worker_thread::get_allocator().deallocate( (my_class*)p, 1 );
}
```

Is there a way I can do the deletion/deallocation as if it didn't have this specialised delete function?

Comment: "overridden `delete()` function" I'm going to regret this, but what is *that*? Do you mean the class has an overridden `operator delete()` that you *don't* want to use ?

Comment: As you can tell, I don't have much experience in C/C++ and memory allocation/deallocation, beyond simple malloc/free stuff. I meant delete operator, not an extra delete function itself (I will edit).

Comment: How was the memory that you want to `delete` allocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try explicitly calling the destructor and then calling operator delete.

```
my_class* p = ...;

p->~my_class();
::operator delete(static_cast<void*>(p));
```

It's not strictly correct but it will probably work. Whether it's a good idea is another issue.

Comment: @WhozCraig Is that needed? I thought any pointer can implicitly be converted to void*.

Comment: I think the asker probably wants to call `free()`, but let him or her clarify.

Comment: @john no it isn't, but I'm paranoid =) I think it will "work" (man is *that* a relative term) either way =) you could nicely [template a function](http://ideone.com/S85mQD) for this hideousness, btw. =P

Comment: @jxh Yes, there is the question of how these objects were allocated in the first place.

Comment: If the class has an overloaded deleter then it probably has an overloaded allocator. So calling delete on it like that is going to do all sorts of nasty things. We need to know what the allocator does. Without that information this is a bad idea.